# Hyperlink to primeng datatable column

Tags: angular, hyperlink, primeng-datatable

how to add hyperlink to primeng datatable column to pass that column value to new window in angular 2 app?

```
<p-column field="name" header ="Name" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" >
    <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
      {{row.name}}
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
```

On click of name in the datatable , have to display name in the text box of new page. Can anyone provide code samples for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the router link , it is working fine.

```
 <p-column field="name" header ="Name" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" >
        <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
          <a [routerLink]="['/newregform',row.name]">{{row.name}}</a>
        </ng-template>
     </p-column>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just add the link inside your ng-template. For example:

```
<p-column field="name" header ="Name" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" >
    <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate type="body">
        <a routerLink="/target/{{row.id}}">{{row.name}}</a>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [provide template for column](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating) and render there all that you need.

Comment: i added the template for the column . can you please tell me how to render it ?